# ReloadSections on collectionview with multiple sections

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to animate the reloading of multiple sections in a collectionView

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
      let updatedSections = Array(0...(self.viewModel?.numberOfSections ?? 0))
      self.collectionView.reloadSections(updatedSections)
}, completion: nil)
```

> Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type
> 'IndexSet'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error states, you're passing an array of integers i.e: `[Int]` when the function expects parameter of type `IndexSet`

You can initialise an `IndexSet` with a range of integers like you did for the `Array`

Replace:

```
let updatedSections = Array(0...(self.viewModel?.numberOfSections ?? 0))
self.collectionView.reloadSections(updatedSections)
```

with:

```
self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...(self.viewModel?.numberOfSections ?? 0)))
```